# Converting a angular 1.x site to Angular 2.6

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm converting a old angular 1.x site and I've come upon a section of the code that I'm stuck at.

Old Code :

```
var loaded = vm.cartMap.on('load', function() {
    loaded.remove();
    setupExtentLayer();
});

function setupExtentLayer() {
    esriLoader.require(['esri/layers/GraphicsLayer'], function (GraphicsLayer) {
        vm.extentLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        vm.cartMap.addLayer(vm.extentLayer);
        if (vm.cartItems.length > 0) {
            _updateCartStatus();
        }
    });
}
```

New Code :

```
const loaded = this.cartMap.on('load', function() {
    loaded.remove();
    this.setupExtentLayer();
 });

setupExtentLayer() {
  loadModules(['esri/layers/GraphicsLayer']).then(([GraphicLayer]) => {
    this.extentLayer = new GraphicLayer();
    this.cartMap.addLayer(this.extentLayer);
    if (this.cartItems.length > 0) {
        this._updateCartStatus();
    }
  });
}
```

My problem is in the angular 2.6 code doesn't recognize the method setupExtentLayer().

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `JS` with context `this`, not in `Angular 2`.

```
this.cartMap.on('load', function() {
    loaded.remove();
    this.setupExtentLayer(); // js this
 }.bind(this)); // bind this to function
```

Comment: This did it.  Thank you Matej!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to bind the `setupExtentLayer` function within the parent class constructor.

something like -

> this.setupExtentLayer = this.setupExtentLayer.bind(this);

Comment: Or much better, use an arrow function.